# Using sub-query within select clause of outer query with group by

Tags: sqlite

Let's say I have two columns 'col1' and 'col2'.

It is many to many relationship.

Let col2 have three kind of values 'A' ,'B' & 'C'

Now I perform group by over col1, and I want to get max of count of A, B, C of col2 for each row in col 1

For example:

```
Col1 | col2
-----+--------------
1.   | A
1.   | A
1.   | B
2.   | C
```

RESULT

```
COL1 | COL2
-----+------
1.   | A
2.   | C
```

I tried writing group by sub-query inside select clause of outer query but I think it doesn't support.

Not getting idea.

Comment: `select distinct col1, col2 from ...`?

Comment: I suggest to point out sql server type you are using: mysql, sql server, postgresql etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Temp Table and Top 1

`SELECT [col2],COUNT(col1) AS mycount into #TMPA 
FROM [TESTDB].[dbo].[tbltest] GROUP BY col1,col2
select top 1 * from  #TMPA GROUP BY col2,mycount
drop table  #TMPA`

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want the "mode" -- the most common value for `col2` for each `col1`.  You can use window functions:

```
select col2 as col2_mode, count(*)
from (select col1, col2, count(*) as cnt,
             row_number() over (partition by col1 order by count(*)) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1
group by col2;
```

If there are ties for the most common, this arbitrarily chooses one of them.  If you want all of them, use `rank()` instead of `row_number()`.

Answer (score 0):

With `ROW_NUMBER()` window function:

```
select col1, col2
from (
  select col1, col2,
    row_number() over (partition by col1 order by count(*) desc)  rn
  from tablename
  group by col1, col2
)
where rn = 1
```

If you want ties includd in the results use `DENSE_RANK()` instead of `ROW_NUMBER()`.
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7yyVT1zVFswutyqkf5Ra6i/0).
Results:

```
| col1 | col2 |
| ---- | ---- |
| 1    | A    |
| 2    | C    |
```